# Do autoregressive coefficients obtained with the Durbin-Levinson algorithm, the Yule-Walker system of equations, and OLS coincide?

Tags: time-series, estimation, bootstrap, autoregressive, resampling

I am applying the sieve bootstrap for time series introduced by Kress (1988), which requires the estimation of autoregressive models with the Durbin-Levinson algorithm (generalized to the multivariate setting by Whittle 1963).

Unfortunately all I can find implemented in R employs OLS estimation (I am working in the multivariate setting). I expect the two methodologies not to differ much, but at the same time I am curious about the differences.
In particular, it seemed to understand that the Durbin-Levinson algorithm coincides to the solution of the Yule-Walker system, which seems of easy implementation.